# Voice Notification can't be turned off?

Tags: notifications, calls, lg-g3

---

I just got the Lg G3, 
Android 4.4.2, and I can't seem to cancel the voice notification off,
it works just fine with my friend's phone, which is the same model and has the same OS version.

I go to settings> Accessibility or Settings>sound>Advanced Settings
and both show me that the message/call voice notifications are ON and locked.
I'd appreciate help asap.
Thanks in advance.